# Definitive refutation of JL Austin?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, linguistic-turn

Within the history of 20th c. philosophy, who gave the most definitive arguments against JL Austin's thought, and his linguistic theory of speech acts in particular? I'm also interested in any accounts that have dealt simultaneously with AJ Ayer.

Comment: There are really few things in philosophy that can be called *definitive*.

Comment: J.R. Searle wrote extensively about speech acts. So did H.P.Grice. Neither attempted to refute Austin. They rather developed his theory. As far as I know, neither wrote about A.J. Ayer. The secondary literature about both focuses on specific topics rather than overall theories. You'll find guidance on what is available in the entries on each at https://plato.stanford.edu/ or https://iep.utm.edu/

Comment: It is hard to give definitive arguments against the obvious, speech acts do happen. Do you have in mind critique of some particular aspects of Austin's theory? If so, please name them in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Austin's theory of illocutionary acts, or [speech acts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/) as John Searle renamed them, has become completely mainstream and an accepted part of the study of the pragmatics of language. I don't think you'll find any refutation of it, though there are plenty of refinements and developments.

Austin was one of the chief exponents of the [ordinary language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_language_philosophy) school of philosophical thought that was popular in Oxford from the 1940s to the late 60s. Philosophers of this school supposed that they could *dissolve* rather than solve philosophical problems just by paying careful attention to how words were ordinarily used. They held that many, if not most, philosophical problems were created by philosophers giving words a special metaphysical meaning that divorced them from their ordinary use. This approach contrasted with earlier philosophers such as Russell who regarded language itself as largely transparent and of little philosophical interest, and considered natural languages to be flawed and in need of being supplemented by formal logic.

Austin considered the ordinary language approach to be a kind of revolution in philosophical thinking, but by the end of the 1960s it was in decline, and while it has influenced some recent philosophers, it is no longer popular. It is difficult to describe Austin's philosophy as having been refuted; it just ran out of steam. While paying careful attention to language can help to illuminate philosophical problems, many such problems have real substance and are not just the product of the misuse of language.

One of the applications of Austin's ordinary language approach was an attack on phenomenalism and in particular the theory of [sense data](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/). Sense data refers to the immediate objects of the senses, taking these to be prior to cognitive acts such as making judgments about the subject of the sensations. A. J. Ayer was an advocate of this theory in his book, "The Foundations of Empirical Knowledge", and this was the main target of a series of lectures by Austin, published in the book, "Sense and Sensibilia". Ayer responded with a paper "Has Austin Refuted the Sense-Datum Theory?" (Synthese, 1967, Vol. 17, pp. 117-140). You'll have to judge for yourself whether Ayer succeeds in rebutting Austin's criticism. Sense data theory is not common today, though some philosophers such as Frank Jackson hold to it.

Comment: Just as an addition: Sense-data theory is essentially dead since Sellars' *Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind*, which refined Austin's arguments a lot. Also, a theory that owes a lot to Austin is Habermas' *Theory of Communicative Acts* and later work in the 80s up to the 2000s.